# How to sort a datatable column which have comma separated days name

Tags: php, sorting, datatable

I have a datatable which have a column called task_days

and this column have names to days with comma separated   like "Mon,Wed,Thu,Sun" and next row have like "Mon,Wed,Sun". I need to sort table if row have today day name in task_days column set it on top .

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The format parameter for getting today's Weekday (Mon / Tue / Wed , etc) is `date('D')` (reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

According to your requirement --- **sort table if row have today day name in task_days column set it on top** , you may use query like the following

1. get those records containing the string
2. union with those records NOT containing the string

Hence, the query is (assuming your tablename is "tablex") :

```
<?php

$string="select * from tablex where task_days like '%". date('D') . "%'";
$string.=" union ";
$string.="select * from tablex where task_days not like '%". date('D') . "%'";


?>
```